# Trim a string until specific character appears

Tags: php, string, api, callback, trim

I want to trim a string and delete everything before a specific character, because I am using an API that gives me some unwanted data in its callback which I want to delete.

The Callback looks like this:

```
{"someVar":true,"anotherVar":false,"items":[  {"id":123456, [...] }
```

And I only want the code after the **[** , so how can I split a string like this?
Thank you!

Comment: its json, use json_decode() then extract what you want! any other method is crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is JSON, so you could just decode it:

```
$data = json_decode($string);
```

If you really want to trim up to a certain character then you can just find the character's position and then cut off everything before it:

```
if (($i = strpos($string, '[')) !== false) {
    $string = substr($string, $i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use various functions. For example:

```
$someVar = explode('[',$string,2);
$wantedData = $someVar[1];
```

Or if you want only data between `[` and `]` then use:

```
$pattern = '~\[([^\]])\]~Ui';
if (preg_match($pattern,$inputString,$matches) {
    $wantedData = $matches[1];
}
```

**Edit:**
Thats what you use if you want extract some string from another. But as @Dagon noticed, it's json and you can use other function to parse it. I will leave above anyway, because it's more general to the question of extracting string from another.